# ipconfig running continuously in the background

Tags: windows, windows-10, ipconfig

The `C:\Windows\System32\ipconfig.exe` file runs every 1 minute in the background and flickers for about 1 second. How can I stop this phenomenon, because it is not allowing me to run an application in fullscreen. Whenever it flickers the windows reduces and comes out to the main screen by minimizing.

Comment: This is abnormal behavior. Most software would use windows APIs to configure or query IP configuration. You might want to try using Process Explorer or Process Monitor to see if you can figure out what program is launching this. In addition, check the version of ipconfig to ensure it actually is ipconfig and not a worm.

Comment: Have you tried to simply reboot your machine?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Discord in the background by chance?

It's a long shot but was happening to me and only when I seemed to have Discord running.

I fixed it by switching windows out of Aero mode (just went with Basic) and it never minimized after that.

- Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Personalization

This was happening to me on windows 10 and Oddly Windows 7 when I reformatted.  That's when I figured it had to be some software I installed. Started around the time of using Discord but it may not be it. I could never see the process as it flashed too quick and was gone once I was tabbed to desktop.

G'Luck!

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)